# JsPDF is not printing all content in scroll view

Tags: javascript, jquery, pdf, jspdf, html2canvas

I am trying to generate pdf file with all content in scroll bar, but it is generating only what ever is showing on screen.

http://jsfiddle.net/gyqu8/139/

```
$(function(){
    $('#menu-button').click(function(){

        var options = {
           "background": '#000',
           format: 'PNG',
           pagesplit: true
        }
        var pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', 'a4');
        pdf.addHTML($('#wrapper'), options, function() {
          pdf.save('web.pdf');
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: fascinating plugin, not seen before. checking their site shows `.addHTML` has been replaced by `.fromHTML` which has a slightly different way of working.

Answer (score 2):

According to their documentation the `.addHTML(` handler has been deprecated. However, via their active demo page their updated handler (which is still a work in progress) at http://rawgit.com/MrRio/jsPDF/master/ under the 'HTML Renderer (early stages)' menu tab. This is adapted a little for your script and jsfiddle:

```
var pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'mm', 'a4');

// We'll make our own renderer to skip this editor
var specialElementHandlers = {
    '#wrapper': function(element, renderer){
        return true;
    }
};

// All units are in the set measurement for the document
// This can be changed to "pt" (points), "mm" (Default), "cm", "in"
pdf.fromHTML($('#wrapper').get(0), 15, 15, {
    'width': 170, 
    'elementHandlers': specialElementHandlers
});
pdf.save('web.pdf');
```

```js
$(function() {
  $('#menu-button').click(function() {
    //$('#wrapper')[0].scrollTop=200;
    var options = {
      "background": '#000',
      format: 'PNG',
      pagesplit: true
    }
    var pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'mm', 'a4');

    // We'll make our own renderer to skip this editor
    var specialElementHandlers = {
      '#wrapper': function(element, renderer) {
        return true;
      }
    };

    // All units are in the set measurement for the document
    // This can be changed to "pt" (points), "mm" (Default), "cm", "in"
    pdf.fromHTML($('#wrapper').get(0), 15, 15, {
      'width': 170,
      'elementHandlers': specialElementHandlers
    });
    pdf.save('web.pdf');
  });
});
```

```css
#container {
  width: 90%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  background: yellow;
}
#wrapper {
  padding: 5px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
#menu-button {
  float: left;
  line-height: 20px;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  background: #555;
  color: white;
}
#topbar {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  background: #ddd;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 1;
  /*for some reason we need a z index now*/
}
#menu {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  color: white;
}
</style> <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0"> <style>
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html2canvas/0.4.1/html2canvas.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.0.272/jspdf.debug.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <div id="topbar" class="slide"><a id="menu-button">Scroll!</a>Scroll button does not work on android4, though interestingly it works on Android 2 even though finger scrolling does not work</div>
  <div id="wrapper" class="slide">
    <ul>
      <li>Content</li>
      <li>Content</li>
      <li>Content</li>
      <li>Content</li>
      <li>Content</li>
      <li>Content</li>
      <li>Content</li>
      <li>Content</li>
      <li>Content</li>
      <li>Content</li>
      <li>Content</li>
      <li>Content</li>
      <li>Content</li>
      <li>Content</li>
      <li>Content</li>
      <li>Content</li>
      <li>Content</li>
      <li>Content</li>
      <li>Content</li>
      <li>Content</li>
      <li>Content</li>
      <li>Content</li>
      <li>Content</li>
      <li>Content</li>
      <li>Content</li>
      <li>Content</li>
      <li>Content</li>
      <li>Content</li>
      <li>Content</li>
      <li>Content</li>
      <li>Content</li>
      <li>Content</li>
      <li>Content</li>
      <li>Content</li>
      <li>Content</li>
      <li>Content</li>
      <li>Content</li>
      <li>Content</li>
      <li>Content</li>
      <li>Content</li>
      <li>Content</li>
      <li>Content</li>
      <li>Content</li>
      <li>Content</li>
      <li>Content</li>
      <li>Content</li>
      <li>Content</li>
      <li>Content</li>
      <li>Content</li>
      <li>Content</li>
      <li>Content</li>
      <li>Content</li>
      <li>Content</li>
      <li>Content</li>
      <li>Content</li>
      <li>Content</li>
      <li>Content</li>
      <li>Content</li>
      <li>Content</li>
      <li>Content</li>
      <li>Content</li>
      <li>Content</li>
      <li>Content</li>
      <li>Content</li>
      <li>Content</li>
      <li>Content</li>
      <li>Content</li>
      <li>Content</li>
      <li>Content</li>
      <li>Prashanth</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is there a way to have a scroll-able list inside the PDF ?

Comment: good question, not that I'm aware of. pdf's aim to behave more like paper spaces than virtual (screen) spaces, the exceptions being where media is embedded. but this might help: https://acrobatusers.com/forum/rich-mediaflash/can-you-embed-live-webpage-pdf/

Comment: yeah that’s what I thought so. I ended up just making screenshots of huge lists lol